# Why the output shows undefined and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 functions:

1. reverseCharacter --> reversing characters
2. checkType        --> checking type String or Number and reversing it
3. newFunction      --> runs through the arrays (arrayTest1, arrayTest2 and arrayTest3), reversing and checking the type of the characters

> ```
> function reverseCharacters(stringToReverse){
>   return stringToReverse.split('').reverse().join('');
> }
>
> function checkType(stringToCheck){
>   if(typeof (stringToCheck) === 'string'){
>     console.log(reverseCharacters(stringToCheck));
>   }
>   else if(typeof (stringToCheck) === 'number'){
>     console.log(reverseCharacters(String(stringToCheck)));
>   }
> }
>
> let arrayTest1 = ['apple', 'potato', 'Capitalized Words'].reverse();
> let arrayTest2 = [123, 8897, 42, 1168, 8675309].reverse();
> let arrayTest3 = ['hello', 'world', 123, 'orange'].reverse();
>
> function newFunction(x){
>   for(let i = 0; i <= x.length; i++){
>     console.log(checkType(x[i]));
>   }
> }
>
> newFunction(arrayTest3);
> newFunction(arrayTest2);
> newFunction(arrayTest1);
> ```

When I run the code I get undefined after each value:

```
egnaro
undefined
321
undefined
dlrow
undefined
olleh
undefined
undefined
9035768
undefined
8611
undefined
24
undefined
7988
undefined
321
undefined
undefined
sdroW dezilatipaC
undefined
otatop
undefined
elppa
undefined
undefined
```

My question is why it says undefined in the output and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has no explicit return statement, therefore it's return value is undefined. You can prove this by adding return "see - no more undefined"; as the last line of the `checkType()` function.

Or, simply remove the `console.log()` part of the call to `checkType()`

```js
function reverseCharacters(stringToReverse){
  return stringToReverse.split('').reverse().join('');
}

function checkType(stringToCheck){
  if(typeof (stringToCheck) === 'string'){
    console.log(reverseCharacters(stringToCheck));
  }
  else if(typeof (stringToCheck) === 'number'){
    console.log(reverseCharacters(String(stringToCheck)));
  }
  return 'See, no more undefined';

}

let arrayTest1 = ['apple', 'potato', 'Capitalized Words'].reverse();
let arrayTest2 = [123, 8897, 42, 1168, 8675309].reverse();
let arrayTest3 = ['hello', 'world', 123, 'orange'].reverse();

function newFunction(x){
  for(let i = 0; i <= x.length; i++){
    console.log(checkType(x[i]));
  }
}

newFunction(arrayTest3);
newFunction(arrayTest2);
newFunction(arrayTest1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite your `newFunction()` like this

```js
function newFunction(x){
  for(let i = 0; i <= x.length; i++){
    //console.log(checkType(x[i]));
    checkType(x[i])
  }
}
```

The error is happening because you were trying to `console.log()` value from `checkType()`. Since `checkType()` does not have any return value, it just logs `reverseCharacters()` return values, you are getting undefined printed.